# How do WordPress.com and Ghost.org create hosted blogs for users on their own website and how can I do the same?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ghost

I am working on a project that is much like **WordPress.com** and **Ghost.org**
I just wanted to know, How these platforms create blogging accounts for their users?

**Do they:**

Just create an account in the database and create a separate *name-spaced database* for the user's website
Or, Do they host the website on separate account using **reseller hosting**?

By the way, I am a **PHP web developer**. So, you can be technical with me :)

Answer (score 1):

Please visit [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-wordpress-to-allow-users-to-create-their-own-blogs-on-my-website)
there is a discussion on this problem, may be helpful to you.That suggests you need to  integrate Word Press MU in your wordpress site.

Comment: I don't wish to create a Multi-User WordPress site. I just want to create website like WordPress.com

Comment: Is that not a multi-user site ?What I have understood from your question is   you want user to have a subdomain on your site when they register and they will have control on that subdomain .Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. You are right but I want to know how I can do something like this:
The user registers for an account on the website and gets a sub domain with wildcard entries and htaccess.
Then he gets complete control over the subdomain. He will be able to login to the subdomain like this sub.mysite.com/admin
Once he logs in, he will be able to see the dashboard and settings. He will be able to add plugins but will not be able to run PHP code outside his subdomain meaning on the main site :)

Comment: You can also do this in PHP but you must ahve good control over your server, so I can suggest a VPS .and you can code for creatinga subdomain for every registration and a installation of wordpress which should be a customized one so that you can limit the user to do things.

Comment: read this how to map a subdomain but still I would suggest you should do this in core PHP if you can https://en.support.wordpress.com/map-subdomain/ and read Again a plugin buddy press take a look at this https://buddypress.org/support/topic/how-to-allow-members-to-create-their-own-blogs/ and https://wordpress.org/support/topic/auto-create-a-site-for-registered-users-as-subdomaindomain

Comment: This will definitely help you https://codex.buddypress.org/buddypress-components-and-features/wordpress-blogs/ Ihave used buddypress to play but not gone for a lot, so I can not guide you too much on this.